# Keyword match from large repository to files

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a set of 400K keywords which needs to be matched with 100K input files.

My current method for achieving this is as below.

**Code:**

```
import glob
with open("keyword.txt") as inp:
    keyword_set=set([lin.strip().lower() for lin in inp])
for fil in glob.glob("file/path/*.txt"):
    with open(fil) as inp, open("output.txt","w") as out:
        file_txt = inp.read().lower()
        for val in keyword_set:
            if val in file_txt:
                out.write("{}\t{}".format(fil, val))
```

**Keyword_Sample:**

```
BUENOS AIRES
Argentina
```

Since I am looping over a large repository it takes a large amount of time(varying from seconds to minute for file.).
Is there any way by which I could increase the through put and reduce the time taken.

Comment: Guess there is only 1 match for each instance from your example? If yes, then add `break` on a new line after your `out.write` at the same indentation level

Comment: @Chris_Rands no that is not the case I have multiple keyword matches for a single file. I am just writing them in separate lines for down stream process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at you code:

```
    file_txt = inp.read().lower()
    for val in keyword_set:
        if val in file_txt:
            out.write("{}\t{}".format(fil, val))
```

The statement

```
        if val in file_txt:
```

looks for the string in text (substring search, time complexity no less than O(n * C) in average case). If you text consists of words (like in your example), you can use more appropriate representation.

For example, to represent all words from `file_txt` as a `set()` (like you second set). If it is possible, of course, you can split the text in file by delimiter. If the keywords can cosist of 2 or more words, you have to add to your set sequential pairs (bigrams) and triplets (trigrams). After that you can search keyword in the set, time complexity of this statement is equals O(1) in average case.

```
import glob
with open("keyword.txt") as inp:
    keyword_set=set([lin.strip().lower() for lin in inp])
for fil in glob.glob("file/path/*.txt"):
    with open(fil) as inp, open("output.txt","w") as out:
        file_txt = inp.read().lower()
        file_set = set(file_txt.split('Your delimiter'))
        # [ adding bigrams (or trigrams) to the set ]
        for val in keyword_set:
            if val in file_set:
                out.write("{}\t{}".format(fil, val))

        # [You can use set intersection operation here instead of cycle]
```

If you want to take into account count of occurences, you have to use `collections.Counter` instead of `set`.

Comment: So what you are saying is to convert the text into a set and do look up. if i have large keywords like 10 words then I must create a set of 10 using the file content and do a look up.

Comment: @Pythonmaster, adding of sequential words into `set/Counter` is good idea. The slow piece if you code is substring searching procedure. If you make performance better, you obtain good final performance.

Comment: Thanks mate your idea does make sense